# Addsubview and dealloc for memory leaks (retainCount)

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, release, addsubview, retaincount

I am check the retainCount for the subview after add to the view. the code is :

```
- (void) loadView{
    //...
    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:nil];
    [[self view] addSubView:toolbar];
}

- (void) dealloc{
    NSLog(@"count=%d", [toolbar retainCount]);   // count=2
    [toolbar removeFromSuperView];
    NSLog(@"count=%d", [toolbar retainCount]);   // count=1
    [toolbar release]
    NSLog(@"count=%d", [toolbar retainCount]);   // count=1
    toolbar = nil;
    NSLog(@"count=%d", [toolbar retainCount]);   // count=0
}
```

From this code in the dealloc{}, I have some questions:

1, the first log retainCount for toolbar is 2, because the toolbar after init and added to the self view, the retaincount will become to 2.

2, After the toolbar removeFromSuperView, the retainCount will become to 1.

3, After the toolbar call the release method, the retainCount is still 1, it can not become 0. In my options, because the super view is remain the toolbar(the self view is not release), so the toolbar can not reduse to 0.

4, If call the toolbar set to nil ,the retainCount will be 0. This log is useless.

My questions is:

a)the toolbar call the removeFromSuperView and the release API, the result is the same, the toolbar retainCount will only become to 1. So If i test the code only use each of them, the result is same. So, can I conclude user can only call each one API is OK?

b)From the apple document, the subview is added to the self view, the self view has remain the toolbar handle, so in the dealloc method, if the viewDidUnload is not called, the toolbar retainCount can not be reduce to 0. If the memory is low, the system will reduce the unuseless view and call the viewDidUnload method, it will automatic reduce the toolbar retainCount to 0. So in the dealloc method, should I set the toolbar to nil. I am confuse if I set the toolbar to nil, when the viewDidUnload method is called, the toolbar will be reduced or not? Is there any momory leak?

Thx.

Comment: But for the subview memory, when the subview will be release release, it should call only the memory is low and in the viewDidUnload method?

Comment: Test in instruments for memory leaks. Checking retain counts like this will tell you nothing.

Comment: You should never use `retainCount`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028512/addsubview-and-dealloc-for-memory-leaks-retaincount#comment14420031_11028512

Comment: I have some memory issue, use the Instruments Allocations for check the momory, the momery will slow increase.

Comment: could you provide the declaration for your `toolbar` property? Is it retain/strong or weak/assign? are you using ARC?

Comment: no, I only declare as an private value.

Comment: can you post the declaration? what does "private value" mean?

Comment: BTW:  `retainCount` can never return 0 (and isn't in your example code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if your code reflects your real code, your `dealloc` method has a big issue:

```
- (void) dealloc{
   [toolbar removeFromSuperView];
   [toolbar release]
   toolbar = nil;
}
```

you are not calling `[super dealloc]`. By not calling [super dealloc], `self.view` will never be released (and eventually deallocated).

This should fix your memory leaks (partially, at least):

```
- (void) dealloc{
    [toolbar release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You can notice that I have removed the call to `removeFromSuperView` because this is automatically done for you when `self.view` is actually deallocated, so you don't need to do it yourself. In any case, calling `removeFromSuperView` does not cause any problem either.

About your questions, I assume that your `toolbar` property is declared as `retain` (based on the code you submit, it is the most sensed hypothesis to me).

If `toolbar` is a `retain` kid of property, then the correct way to assign to it a newly created view is:

```
 toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:nil] autorelease];
```

please, note the `autorelease`; if it is not there your retain/release calls are impaired. that could explain the need for you to first call `release` then `nil` the property in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
 ...
    [toolbar release]
    toolbar = nil;
 ....
}
```

by doing like that you are releasing `toolbar` twice; but since you did not use `autorelease` when assigning to the retain property, this will produce the correct result.

> a)the toolbar call the removeFromSuperView and the release API, the result is the same, the toolbar retainCount will only become to 1. So If i test the code only use each of them, the result is same. So, can I conclude user can only call each one API is OK?

as I said, you don't need to call directly `removeFromSuperView` to get a subview to be released at `dealloc` time, since `self.view` will do that for you. It is a different matter when you want to remove a subview while still keeping the `superview` around (imagine you display a label and then remove it); in this case you need to call both, otherwise you have a leak.

> b)From the apple document, the subview is added to the self view, the self view has remain the toolbar handle, so in the dealloc method, if the viewDidUnload is not called, the toolbar retainCount can not be reduce to 0. If the memory is low, the system will reduce the unuseless view and call the viewDidUnload method, it will automatic reduce the toolbar retainCount to 0. So in the dealloc method, should I set the toolbar to nil. I am confuse if I set the toolbar to nil, when the viewDidUnload method is called, the toolbar will be reduced or not? Is there any momory leak?

if I understand your doubt correctly, the point is that if you sent the `toolbar` property to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`, then when this method is called (either when you explicitly delete the view or when a memory warning is issued) your subview is correctly disposed of; if `dealloc` for your controller is called henceforth, your property has already a `nil` value, so releasing it will not have any effect (but that is fine, since it was already released in `viewDidUnload`).

On the other hand, if you do not release your property in `viewDidUnload` then what happens is that in case the view is displayed again after a memory warning, then `loadView`/`viewDidLoad` is called again; but in this case, when you create the toolbar subview and assign its reference to the `toolbar` property (assuming it is `retain` kind), then the older object is automatically released for you, so you don't have any memory leak; what happens is that you are using a bit more memory that you could possibly do (since the toolbar is not deallocated until when `self.view` is created again).

Comment: sorry, i fogot to line the super.

Comment: You forgot:  "retainCount is useless.  Don't call it."